# python requests 403 error

Tags: python, django

*i am getting serialized model objects and return them as json*

**request:**

```
data={'Page':1}
```

`r=requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/GetTenders',data=data)`

**Django view**

```
def GetTenders(request):
    if request.is_ajax() or request.POST:
        page_num = int(request.POST.get('Page'))
        if page_num != 1:
            start = (page_num - 1) * 4
            objs = Tender.objects.all()[start:(start + 4)]
            return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json',objs), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            objs = Tender.objects.all()[:4]
            return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', objs), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^GetTenders$', views.GetTenders,name='gettenders'),
```

**result**

```
>>>r
<Response [403]>
>>>r.url
u'http://127.0.0.1:8000/GetTenders'
```

Django view called by ajax but i want to test before using

***Solved by Removing request.is_ajax() and put decorator 
@csrf_exempt before view***

Comment: r=requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/GetTenders',data=data) the same error

Comment: You are getting a forbidden error? What in your code would cause that?

Comment: HTTP 403 is [forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). It doesn't look like you have authenticated anywhere. Should that request be accepted anonymously?

Comment: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /GetTenders
[19/Apr/2016 03:40:13] "POST /GetTenders HTTP/1.1" 403 2629

Comment: ''request be accepted anonymously" it should but error in cmd like that  "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /GetTenders"

Comment: @cricket_007 i dont have a template it a function  called by ajax and i want to test before using

Comment: @cricket_007       !!!  CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False the same error

Comment: Solved by Removing request.is_ajax() and but decorator @csrf_exempt before view